# Image not visible in Email, after email is sent using .Net.Mail Class

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, email

I need to send a HTML content as Email, If the HTML has any image..it dosent show uo in the Email.

I cannot attach the image to the mail
The Image will be inside HTML, which i get from a CMS

How can i solve this issue ?

Comment: Without the HTML that builds the email it's impossible to help. Chances are that the path to the image is wrong, your images can't be accessed externally or your html is invalid and causing issues in the mail client.

Comment: you can have the image in your server and have a link to it in the html like <img src="http://yourdomain.com/static/images/<imagename>.ext">

Comment: Senthil Kumar, that worked...Thanks. How can i accept ur answer now ?

Answer (score 3):

Are you adding image as linked resource? Here is an example how to do this: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/34467/Sending-Email-Using-Embedded-Images

```
using System.Net.Mail;

string htmlBody = "<html><body><h1>Picture</h1><br><img src=\"cid:Pic1\"></body></html>";
AlternateView avHtml = AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString
    (htmlBody, null, MediaTypeNames.Text.Html);

// Create a LinkedResource object for each embedded image
LinkedResource pic1 = new LinkedResource("pic.jpg", MediaTypeNames.Image.Jpeg);
pic1.ContentId = "Pic1";
avHtml.LinkedResources.Add(pic1);


// Add the alternate views instead of using MailMessage.Body
MailMessage m = new MailMessage();
m.AlternateViews.Add(avHtml);

// Address and send the message
m.From = new MailAddress("rizwan@dotnetplayer.com", "Rizwan Qureshi");
m.To.Add(new MailAddress("shayan@dotnetplayer.com", "Shayan Qureshi"));
m.Subject = "A picture using alternate views";
SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("smtp.dotnetplayer.com");
client.Send(m);
```

Comment: +1 Very nice. I did not know it could be done like this. It looks simple enough.

Answer (score 0):

In all HTML e-mails that cannot have the images attached, all images must be placed in a server and be referenced in the HTML with their full path e.g. "http://www.yourdomain.com/images/imagename.ext". Casing IS important, and it is the most common cause for images not appearing.

Comment: When I say "that cannot have the images attached" I mean that, if, for any reason, the images cannot be attached to the e-mail. embending the images is tricky and do not work well with some e-mail clients. I have done some tests and, in those tests, the images were displayed fine in Thunderbird but MSOutlook refused to display them at all.